# how to align text under image in css menu

Tags: html, css

I want to align menu text at the bottom of image how to i achieve it?

**Expected output:**

```
Image    Image    Image    Image
[menutext]    [menutext][menutext]    [menutext]
```

**Actual output :**

```
Image[menutext]      Image[menutext]      Image[menutext]      Image[menutext]
```

**my Css Code:**

```
#vilaniHeader
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: Black;
}

#vilaniHeader h1
{
    padding-left: 15%;
    font: Arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
#vilaniHeader #menu
{
    color: #ffffff;
    font: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30%;
}

#vilaniHeader #menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;

}
#vilaniHeader #menu li
{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    float: none;
    text-align:center;

}

#vilaniHeader #menu a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#vilaniHeader #menu .menuHome
{
    color: red;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:50px;
    background-image:url:("Styles/menuHome.png") ;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

**and My HTML code**

```
<div id="vilaniHeader">
                <h1>
                   Comany name
                </h1>
                <div id="menu">
                 <ul>
                 <li class="menuHome"><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" />Home</li>
                 <li><a href="About.aspx">Car</li>
                 <li><a href="About.aspx">Mobile</li>
                 <li><a href="About.aspx">OldThings</li>
                 <li><a href="About.aspx">Matrimoni</li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want menu text should be align at the bottom of the image plese help me to do that.

Comment: You could have simplified the example to ease it for us (especially the CSS, too much).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution building upon the answer here from tejash. My answer validates and is search engine friendly.

- I prefered to use links within a div but I imagine this will work with an ul
- I use a background image that does not show if CSS is disabled
- I use a span set displayed as block because a div inside an a tag does not validate
- I use a class to place the image but use ids if you want different pics for each link
- Change the width + heights to suit your needs

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#"><span class="image"></span><span>About Us</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="image"></span><span>Investors</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav a {
    display:block; 
    float: left;
    width:100px; 
}
.image {
    display:block;
    background: url("myimage.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
    height:40px;
    width:100px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `img` a block element so it takes the full width / line-breaks afterwards.

```
#menu li { display:block; }
```

That’s all.

Comment: its not helping me to get expected result

Comment: Simple example works for me: `<style>
img {display:block;}
</style>
<ul>
<li><img src="img.jpg"/>Name</li>
<li><img src="img.jpg"/>Name</li>
</ul>`

Comment: If you still have problems, please either * simplify the example, or * paste your page where one can inspect it, like http://pastehtml.com/view/aw3nujv88.html .

Comment: @kissaki  i tried above solution but the menu are displayed vertically i want to display them horyzontally how do i do that . I have set li item to  display: inline; still now its showing vertically

Comment: You `li { display:inline; }` should do that. You will have to keep that for that purpose of course.

Comment: Pramod, please select this answer if it solved your problem so the question does not remain as unanswered. If a mod reads this...select it for him please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, obviously replacing the image sample I used. For the link to work, you can use a jQuery click event on `LI`, so it searches for the link inside the clicked `LI` and then opens the desired link.

http://jsfiddle.net/WcePK/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuHome"><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" />Home</li>
    <li style="background-image: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png')"><a href="About.aspx">Car</a></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png')"><a href="About.aspx">Mobile</a></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png')"><a href="About.aspx">OldThings</a></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png')"><a href="About.aspx">Matrimoni</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
LI {
      float: left;
      margin: 5px;
      padding: 50px 10px 10px;
      min-width: 100px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center 10px;
      background-color: #366D93;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer
}
```

Comment: That’s over-complicated and using background images if often not desired. Background is styling and can/could be omitted, whereas an `img` is content.

Comment: I really don't see where is it "over-complicated", but agree about style and content, although it's not clear whether the user wants to use the images as content or stylish.

Comment: For links you usually use the `a` element and not a jQuery click event... I guess your links don't work because you didn't close them correctly. And if you want the image to be clickable too, put the `a` around it.

Comment: @Midas: Sorry, I just copied & pasted the source example, WITHOUT the closing `A`... Thanks! And if you realize, as I told, the link would still be preserved inside the LI.

Comment: @Tuco: Well, you can fix that by moving the `padding` and `min-width` from `li` to `a` and setting `a` to `display:inline-block`. This way the link should fill the parent `li` element.

Comment: @Midas: Nice, it's really a nicer approach. Thanks for sharing it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest add some wrapper on text and make image and wrapper both display:block;
You can use span tag as an wrapper for text.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" /><span>Home</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

li img, li span
{
 display:block;
}

Comment: `Span` is a non-semantic `inline` block, whereas `div` is a non-semantic `block` (pendant). Why should one use `span` and then make it `block` instead of using `div` right away? There is no reason to.

Comment: yeah you are right, you can use div directly. And that's why i said use some wrapper on text but span comes first in mind. Sorry for that

Comment: Using `span` and setting `display:block` like tejash says is better here, because without CSS the text should be displayed next to the image. Also this solution doesn't work because you can't center an `img` when it's `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text to overlay your image, but at the bottom, you should try to play around with the `line-height` property. That will cause your text to move down, so it will be in the center of it's line.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions for you. `style1` works for items with text smaller than the image. `style2` works for items with text wider than the image. Easiest is to make sure that the images are always wider or smaller than the text, so that you need only one style.

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    list-style:none
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    text-align:center
}
#menu .style1 img, #menu .style2 span {
    overflow:hidden
}
#menu .style1 span, #menu .style2 img {
    display:block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vilaniHeader">
    <h1>Comany name</h1>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="style1"><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" width="10" alt="" /> <span>Home</span></li>
        <li class="style2"><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" width="100" alt="" /> <span>Car</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not a `span`-fan but it seems like you can't do it without here.

---

BTW, why don't you just add a `br`?

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    list-style:none
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    text-align:center
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vilaniHeader">
    <h1>Comany name</h1>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" width="10" alt="" /><br />Home</li>
        <li><img src="Styles/menuHome.png" width="100" alt="" /><br />Car</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I guess that's the most easy and reliable solution.